# Stored Procedure Error Message - adding explicit type casts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

This is my first post as I am trying to become more familiar with SQL.  Im working on a project where I have to create a stored procedure, but I cannot figure out what this error message is asking me to do.  I want the procedure to calculate the sum of the total profit for the date being input.  order_date is data type DATE - and it accepts the procedure, but when I call the procedure and input the date, it gives the error below.  I have been troubleshooting this for HOURS and any input would be great!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE daily_profits (IN order_date DATE, OUT total_profit INTEGER)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$
        BEGIN
             SELECT SUM(profit) AS total_profit
             FROM orders
             WHERE orders.order_date = daily_profits.order_date;
        END;
    $$; 
    

CALL daily_profits('2016-10-11');

ERROR:  procedure daily_profits() does not exist
LINE 1: CALL daily_profits(); 
             ^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 6
```

Comment: Even if you get around that error, the procedure won't work. A procedure isn't meant to return a result. If you want that, use a  function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, from Postgres 14 on procedures can have `OUT` parameters and return them per [Release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html): 'Stored procedures can now return data via OUT parameters.'

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

`CALL daily_profits('2016-10-11', NULL);`

per here [Function/procedure arguments](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS):

> In a call to a procedure, all the parameters must be specified. For output parameters, NULL may be specified when calling the procedure from plain SQL:

So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utility.daily_profits(IN order_date date, OUT total_profit integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
        BEGIN
            RAISE NOTICE '%', order_date;
        END;
    $procedure$
```

then:

```
CALL daily_profits('2016-10-11', null);
NOTICE:  10/11/2016
 total_profit 
--------------
         NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string into the SP and it us expecting a date - so you need to cast '2016-10-11' to a date

Comment: That is not the issue it will accept the string as a date. See my answer for the actual issue.